# "Error - No Network Interface available" when running TubeMaster++

Tags: windows-xp, download, open-source, network-adapter, video-capture

Each time I start [TubeMaster++ 2.6](http://www.tubemaster.net/), I receive this error:

> **No Network Interface available !**  TubeMaster++ cannot find any suitable network interface to capture data ! Please make sure you are running the program as administrator.

However, I already have administrator privileges.  I also have the Java Runtime and WinPcap components installed.

How can I successfully run this application without getting the error?

I'm using XP Home SP 3.  AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4400+, 1.9GB RAM, NVIDIA GeForce 6100 nForce 405.

Comment: I notice when I run Windows Update, it recommends these two optional hardware updates - "Advanced Micro Devices - Other Hardware - AMD Processor" and "nVidia - Network - NVIDIA Network Bus Enumerator".  Could this have anything to do with why I get the error when I run TubeMaster++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a USB modem to connect to the Internet.  Unfortunately, the WinPcap library (which TubeMaster++ uses) apparently does not support some USB devices.